# Preview failing to parse double backslash in large matrices?

Tags: bug, mathjax, markdown-preview

A couple of times now, I've been entering a large matrix here or on math.SE and, in the preview window, all the rows appear on a single line. Once the question posts, it displays correctly. I most recently ran into this bug on [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/352463/).

I'm afraid this is somewhat of a Heisenbug: I just tried to reproduce by (1) editing my question, (2) copy-pasting my equation into a new ask box and (3) manually copy-typing the matrix into a new ask box, and none of them reproduced the bug. It has happened to me a few times now, though.

Has anyone else seen this? Does anyone have a reliable way to reproduce it?

Comment: On my smartphone, posts with matrices sometimes appear as a single line before being rerendered correctly which can take several seconds for me.  This might be a browser dependent issue.  Gerhard "So Do Some More Testing" Paseman, 2020.02.11.

Comment: Not only in large matrices, but also in multi-line displayed formulae. The problem seems to be intermittent (it occurs on some occasions  but not always). Triple slash is the way to force the (approximately) correct behavior (if it switches to working correctly, you just have an extra space in your formula, which screws up alignment a bit but still preserves readability)

Comment: FWIW, some chat on the tag [meta-tag:markdown-preview] here: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2020/2/19